# What's the fastest way to assign values to rows in python?

Tags: python, pandas, performance, dataframe

I have a code that runs a simulation for 21 days in which n number of orders arrive a day and some values have to be assigned to the orders which are generated from random sampling another data frame. this simulation has to run 100 times to calculate some cumulative statistics. I have tried two approaches but they take so long so I am looking for a way to speed this up.

Approach #1:

```py
def get_values():
    index=random.randint(0,(len(shipments)-1))#generate number
    country,segment,time,weight,costs,carrier=shipments[['SHIP TO COUNTRY','SEGMENT','TRANSIT TIME','OTM_WEIGHT','TOTAL_TRANSPORT_COST','CARRIER']].iloc[index] #data sampling using the random number created
    costs=round(costs,2)
    return[country,segment,time,weight,costs,carrier]
def get_arrival(): 
    index=random.randint(0,len(daily_arrivals)-1)
    arrival=(daily_arrivals['DELIVERY DATE'].iloc[index])
    return(arrival)
def LC_run(env,df,j,balance,dispatch,orders):
    while True:
      arrival=get_arrival()
      for m in range(arrival):
          order_nmbr='order #{}'.format(m)
          pickup=env.now
          country,segment,time,weight,cost,carrier=get_values()
          delivery=(pickup+time)
          df.loc[len(df)]=[order_nmbr,country,segment,pickup,delivery,time,weight,cost,carrier,j]
          balance+=cost
          dispatch+=weight
          orders+=1
      
      yield env.timeout(1)
      

df=pd.DataFrame(columns=['Order #','SHIP TO COUNTRY','SEGMENT','PICK UP DATE','DELIVERY DATE','TRANSIT TIME','OTM_WEIGHT', 'TRANSPORTATION COST','CARRIER','SIM_RUN']) 
pdf=pd.DataFrame(columns=['SIM_RUN','TOTAL_TRANSPORTATION_COST','TOTAL_WEIGHT','TOTAL_NUMBER_OF_ORDERS'])  
for j in range(10):
    global balance, dispatch, orders
    balance=0
    dispatch=0
    orders=0
   #how many times is the simulation running 
    env = simpy.Environment()
    env.process(LC_run(env,df,j,balance,dispatch,orders))    
    env.run(until=21) #how long is the simulation running until
    
    pdf.loc[len(pdf)]=[j,balance,dispatch,orders]
    print('run #{}'.format(j))
```

Approach #2 *Note pick up time is not important but was an extra to add also in this one I run the simulation for a day instead of the 21 days and instead of having n of arrivals I have an arrival rate

```py
def get_values():
    index=random.randint(0,(len(shipments)-1))#generate number
    country,segment,time,weight,costs,carrier=shipments[['SHIP TO COUNTRY','SEGMENT','TRANSIT TIME','OTM_WEIGHT','TOTAL_TRANSPORT_COST','CARRIER']].iloc[index] #data sampling using the random number created
    costs=round(costs,2)
    return[country,segment,time,weight,costs,carrier]
def get_arrival(): 
    index=random.randint(0,len(daily_arrivals)-1)
    arrival=(24/daily_arrivals['DELIVERY DATE'].iloc[index])
    #print(arrival)
    return(arrival)

def LC_run(env,df,i,arival,j,balance,dispatch,orders):
    while True:

      order_nmbr='order #{}'.format(orders)
      pickup=i
      pick_up_time=('{} day, {} hours').format(i, i+(env.now*24))
      country,segment,time,weight,cost,carrier=get_values()
      delivery=(pickup+time)
      df.loc[len(df)]=[order_nmbr,country,segment,pickup,pick_up_time,delivery,time,weight,cost,carrier,j]
      
      yield env.timeout(arrival)
      balance+=cost
      dispatch+=weight
      orders+=1

df=pd.DataFrame(columns=['Order #','SHIP TO COUNTRY','SEGMENT','PICK UP DATE','PICKUP TIME','DELIVERY DATE','TRANSIT TIME','OTM_WEIGHT', 'TRANSPORTATION COST','CARRIER','SIM_RUN']) 
pdf=pd.DataFrame(columns=['SIM_RUN','TOTAL_TRANSPORTATION_COST','TOTAL_WEIGHT','TOTAL_NUMBER_OF_ORDERS'])  
for j in range(10):
    global balance, dispatch, orders
    balance=0
    dispatch=0
    orders=0
    for i in range(21):#how many times is the simulation running 
        env = simpy.Environment()
        arrival=get_arrival()
        env.process(LC_run(env,df,i,arrival,j,balance,dispatch,orders))    
        env.run(until=24) #how long is the simulation running until
    
    pdf.loc[len(pdf)]=[j,balance,dispatch,orders]
    print('run #{}'.format(j))
```

Comment: It will likely be much faster to build up two python datastructures and convert them to dataframes at the end rather than creating an empty dataframe and appending rows one-by-one. Also pandas has built-in sampling.

Answer (score 0):

loc is not so fast, **df.iloc[-1]** can speed up, here 3 differents approach:

```
%timeit df.loc[len(df)] = [99, 'abc', .23, now, 99]
2.61 ms ± 94.2 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100 loops each)

%timeit df.values[-1,:] = [99, 'abc', .23, now, 99]
5.59 ms ± 291 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100 loops each)

%timeit df.iloc[-1] = [99, 'abc', .23, now, 99]
1.03 ms ± 88.3 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1000 loops each)
```